# Is golang supported in Android Things?

Tags: go, android-things

Can we use golang in *Android Things*?

I would like to program in *golang* an IoT app, however I don't find support for *golang* in *Android Things*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of Android application developer Android Things is pretty much the same. So if you can write Android apps in Go, you can do the same for Android Things app development.

Comment: And it is possible to write Android app in Go as described [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile)

Comment: Is there some libraries available in golang to interface with the hardware? Such as PIO.

Comment: @Crapsy, couldn't find any. I've never written in Go but assume you might make use of PIO APIs in Java / Kotlin and then use bindings to GO. Or, if applicable, use [Native PIO](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/native). Here is the [official sample](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-nativepio).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Android Things offers just a lightweight version of Android.

Go supports mobile platforms such as android and IOS:
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile

It still uses java/objective-c bindings though

Also check if you need Android Things, because there is nice framework: 
https://gobot.io/#platforms
designed for iot.

Comment: _"As far as I know the Android Things offers just a lightweight version of Android"_ What is this statement based on?